# Drawing graph with bargraph.pl script

Tags: perl, graph

I am trying to draw a bar graph with the script from this site http://www.burningcutlery.com/derek/bargraph/ but I am getting the following error on my screen. Any ideas

```
perl bargraph.pl -gnuplot -fig -png scenario1.perf 
sh: fig2dev: not found
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-XXpiZBkY' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename `-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2970.
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `fig2dev`. It looks like you need to install a `transfig` package as described in the "Caveats and Future Work" section on the bargraph page you linked. How you do that depends on what OS you're running.